Radial distance of a particle as function of time
How can we express the radial distance of a particle from a fixed point as a function of time, given that the position vector of the particle rotates with a constant angular velocity about that fixed point?

If it rotates about the fixed point, why does the radial distance change at all?

In any case, this question does not have a unique answer as it is currently stated: the length of the position vector from a fixed point can vary arbitrarily even when the direction changes evenly.

@George You need to clarify what thought experiment you have in mind. Is the particle connected to rod that is forced to rotate at a constant angular velocity and the particle is free to slide along that rod? As naturllyinconsistent pointed out, if the particle is inertially moving in a straight line, the angular velocity is not constant. Did you mean constant angular momentum? That would make more sense.  I did not vote to to close the question, but you definitely need to clarify what you have in mind. The question as it stands is not clear.

@George You have not stated how your particle is moving. In a straight line or a curve? Inertially or otherwise? if the angular velocity is constant then the particle must be moving in a circle and then the answer is that trivially, the radial distance remains constant by definition. I do not think that is what you intended, but we shouldn't have to guess what your question is about.

The particle is moving along a curve, the particle is moving with a constant angular velocity w.r.t a point on the circumference of the circle rather on the center hence, it has varying radial distance

The simplest interpretation is that the particle is moving in a circle around a point P which is not at the origin and is fixed and you want to know the radial distance of the particle from the origin as a function of time. Is that what you had in mind?

Is the point P that the particle is rotating around also moving in a circle around the origin? Please note that "constant angular velocity" does not by itself, define motion in a circle.

You assert that it "has varying radial distance", but what does "constant angular velocity w.r.t. a point on the circumference of the circle RATHER ON the center" even mean? That does not seem to be proper English. Where is your origin, what is the criteria for constant angular velocity, what does all your terms mean?

@George I have added a drawing to my answer that represents what I think you have in mind. Is it correct?

EDIT: This answer is on hold pending clarification by the OP on what the question actually is. Please do not upvote or downvote in the meantime. The diagram immediately below is what I think the OP has in mind and I am putting this diagram here as part of the process of establishing what the actual scenario is:

In the above diagram point P on the end of arm (f) is rotating around the origin (A) and particle G on the end of arm (g) is rotating around point P with constant angular velocity. Are you requesting the radial distance from A to particle G as a function of time?
The rest of this answer should be ignored until the question is clarified:
==============================================
I assume you mean the particle is inertial and moving in a straight line and is not connected to the fixed point (P), otherwise its radial distance would remain constant over time.
Lets assume the particle has a velocity of v in the x direction only. We can arrange this by rotating the coordinates as required. Lets define $R_0$ as the radial distance at the point of closest approach to P and define this event as occurring at time t=0 and x =0, so its coordinates at this event are $(x,y,t) = (0,R_0, 0)$. It x coordinate as a function of time is simply $v \times t$. Its y coordinate remains unchanged over time. Using Pythagoras, its radial distance from P as a function of time is simply $R= \sqrt{(vt)^2 + R_0^2}$.
For the more general case when there is motion in both the x and y directions so $v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}$ the equation becomes:
$$R= \sqrt{(v_x^2 + v_y^2) t^2 + R_0^2}.$$

there is no "constant angular velocity" in this

@naturallyInconsistent     oops, you are right. I better try and fix that.

I falsely assumed constant angular momentum...

That's why I voted to close the question; it lacked details necessary to even arrive at a solution.

I agree. The closure and down vote of my answer was justified. Hopefully the OP will clarify what he meant and then I can try and fix my answer to match.

Yes, and when the edit comes through, then I can undo the downvote.
